# Javascript Proxy: detect recursions

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple performance logger:

```
function makePerformanceMeasured(target) {
    return new Proxy(target, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {
            if(!target.name) {
                throw 'The function must have a name'
            }
            console.time(target.name);
            const result = target.apply(thisArg, args); 
            console.timeEnd(target.name);
            return result;
        }
    })
}
```

for non-recursional functions - all works well:

```
function isPrime(n) {
    if(n < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
} 
isPrime = makePerformanceMeasured(isPrime); 
isPrime(100); // 0.001ms false
```

But with recursional functions:

```
function fact(n) {
    if(n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
fact = makePerformanceMeasured(fact);
fact(4);
// 0.025ms 
// 0ms
// 0ms
// 24
```

I want to detect in the Proxy `apply` trap - if the function has been called recursively - make time measurements only for first function call in the stack.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a flag to remember whether you're already inside a call:

```
function makePerformanceMeasured(target) {
    var isCalled = false;
    return new Proxy(target, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {
            if (!isCalled) {
                 console.time(target.name);
                 isCalled = true;
                 const result = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
                 isCalled = false;
                 console.timeEnd(target.name);
                 return result;
            } else {
                 return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `Reflect`? What's that? It looks like you didn't only add the flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect

Comment: @Kinduser, my point was that it's better to explain what's added, and _why_. The first thing I did was to look `Reflect` up on MDN, but you can't expect that from users. That said, I don't see the point of that change.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, yeah, agreed. Bergi please add some explanation how and why does it work with `Reflect`. I'm curious and I guess theres much more ppl who are interested aswell.

Comment: @Cerbrus `target.apply` might be overwritten, `Reflect.apply` does exactly what would've happened without the proxy trap (that's what the `Reflect` object was introduced for). I didn't comment on it because it doesn't really matter for the question.

Comment: Imo, if it doesn't matter, don't change it. If you _do_ change it, explain it (briefly). I'd suggest adding that comment to the answer, @Bergi.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. As I understand - Reflect.apply here - is kind of a 'good style'? But generally does the same as target.apply?

Comment: @ArslArsl Yes, mostly style and a tiny bit of correctness/safety. In all usual cases they will behave the same.

Comment: https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/wiki#more-reliable-function-application

Comment: @ArslArsl The [*default forwarding* chapter](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/wiki#default-forwarding-behavior-for-proxy-traps) seems more relevant. But good find!